# Is there a way to stop propagation of keyboard shortcuts in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Here's the code I'm using and the methods I've tried already, they work in Chrome and Firefox:

```
$j(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 80) {
        if(ctrl_key == 'yes') {
            do_something();

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();    
            e.cancelBubble = true;      

        }
    }
});

$j(document).on('keypress keyup', function (e) {
if(e.keyCode == 80) {
    if(ctrl_key == 'yes') {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();    
        e.cancelBubble = true;      
    }
}
});
```

This is for the print function (ctrl + p)

Is there any way top stop this behavior?

Comment: In general, keycode can only be logged for modifier keys (like Ctrl, and Shift) if the event is of type 'keypress'.

Comment: @ChenAsraf That's not my problem here, I'm checking the state of the Ctrl and Shift separately (the ctrl_key variable is 'yes' if the key is pressed). My problem is that I can't get it to stop propagatin outwards or to stop showing the default print window.

Comment: So you're trying to stop the default print window? Have you tried overriding `window.print()`? (`window.print = function() {...}`) or for IE, I think it's `window.onbeforeprint` that you can use

Comment: FYI, since it seems you are using jQuery, calling `e.stopPropagation();` is enough. jQuery takes care of the browser differences.

Answer (score 2):

Cross-browsers method :

```
$j(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
    var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
    if(e.ctrlKey && key == 80) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();  
        alert("CTRL + P pressed");
        return false;
    }
});
```

You need to select the "document", click in the render panel or in the edit box before test http://jsfiddle.net/PTauw/99/

Comment: This works in IE with the alert but anything else and it still shows the print window. For example http://jsfiddle.net/PTauw/101/

Comment: It makes no sense... sorry, IE behaviour is wird.

Comment: After testing, the script can block the save dialog (ctr+s), but not the print dialog. I really don't know why.